# Can I mix 2GB RAM with 4GB RAM in my HP 635?

Tags: laptop, memory

I have question that is probably allready answerd but I read so many answers that now I am confused (some said it's ok some said it's not ok it would hurt performance)

My laptop HP 635
- [Link for HP 635](http://specsen.com/laptops-hp/hp-635-a1e47ea-e-300-1300-mhz-15-6-1366x768-2048mb-320gb-dvd-rw-ati-radeon-hd-6310m-wi-fi-bluetooth-linux-/)

Memory in HP 635: 
(Samsung 2GB PC3 SODIMM PC10600, M471B5773DH0-CH9, 204 Pin 1Rx8 DDR3 Non  ECC PC, 1333MHz)

Memory that I would add
- [Link for memory that would put add](http://www.lost.hr/hr/izdvajamo/item/17219-kingmax-so-dimm-4gb-ddr3-1333mhz-204-pin)

Would this work?

If yes, on what should I pay attention to in the future so I don't spin in circles and asking questions that have already been explained?

Comment: Possible duplicates:
http://superuser.com/questions/696433/can-i-have-two-different-capacity-ram-sticks,
http://superuser.com/questions/381726/can-i-mix-different-ram-modules-in-pc,
http://superuser.com/questions/43407/can-i-mix-1gb-and-2gb-sticks-of-ram-in-the-same-machine

Interesting to also read:
http://superuser.com/questions/821772/can-i-mix-an-8gb-chip-with-a-4gb-chip-and-still-get-dual-channeling,
http://superuser.com/questions/952370/can-i-use-two-different-speeds-of-ram-in-one-laptop,
http://superuser.com/questions/623155/how-safe-is-it-to-mix-ram

Comment: Whoever said that it would hurt performance is wrong. Adding a second SODIIMM to a system already containing one does not lower performance.

What they might have wanted to say is: If you already have a system with two DIMM and have a motherboard capable of taking advantage of that, then adding a third DIMM might cause conflicts. **Might**. Usually performance is improved by more memory and you gain much more than you loose in the little extra bandwith from dual channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically yes the RAM you would add should work. I'd check the manual for the laptop to ensure it supports a broad range of memory addition. Dual-channel setups may, for example, give you problems unless you are using two of the exact same kits.

RAM spec matching:

- ECC: ECC RAM and non-ECC RAM cannot be mixed.
- Generation: DDR3 must be matched with DDR3, DDR4 with DDR4, etc..
- Frequency: This has a little bit of wiggle room, but for best results
  always match the frequency (measured in MHz).
- Other considerations: Especially with laptops, be sure to read the
  manual that came with the laptop (or motherboard, if this is a
  desktop or similar). Some motherboards do not support anything other
  than exact kit matches (same SKU, literally the same stick of RAM)

Also please check out https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "just make sure your addition is the same type as the existing RAM" - What do you mean by that same type? "(although generally not recommended, you can sometimes mix and match this with the understanding that you will be stuck with the lower value)" On this you mean MHZ or differente sizes of RAM?

Comment: To your first point, mixing ECC RAM and non-ECC RAM will not work. To your second point, I am talking about frequency which in this case is 1333 MHz.

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: I've read some manufacturer manual and came acros where they mention that for max performance it is best to use in both slots same type, size and frequency. So i found on ebay same Samsung RAM but  just 4gb each. Thank you very very much for help.