# Can I mix 4gb RAM with 2gb RAM in my Precision T1700?

Tags: memory, ddr3

I have a question that is probably somewhere I can't find, but anyways wanted to ask can I mix (Hynix 2gb 2rx8 PC3 - 10600U - 9 - 10 - B0 HMT125U6BFR8C - H9 NO AA - C 1003) with (DDRIII1333 4GB CL9 MDCB334G28-9E02   1144)My PC Precision T1700, here's the link:https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-uk/sln290792/precision-t1700-desktop-workstation-hardware-specifications?lang=en

Comment: http://www.crucial.com

Comment: Kudos on sorting your question out. As you can see, you've now garnered a sensible response.

Answer (score 0):

Both memory sticks you've referenced are DDR3 (same generation) 1333MHz (same frequency) sticks, neither with ECC. In theory, this should work, yes. See SU 'Related' questions to learn more info about potential conflicts (for example, [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1107051/)).

Ideally, you can use matching size (e.g. 2x 4GB) rather than mixing. It may make some difference to put the 4GB stick in slot 0 and the 2GB stick in slot 2 (leaving slots 1 & 3 empty). Refer to your computer manual for more info.